# PIL & NumPy array -- extracting shapes based on color (black&white)

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library

I have a black & white image where the background contains only black pixels while digits/characters are all white (see attached image).

[image]

The image is coming from PIL and then is converted to a NumPy array.

I'd like to be able to extract each character/digit (ideally with 1px black border) into a separate NumPy arrays/images.

I'm pretty new to PIL and NumPy so my only idea now is to manually iterate over the array and verify each pixel's color to get coordinates to cut the image in the right places.

Is there any other (easier/more performant) solution?

Comment: Maybe you can iterate over the columns of the image and see where all of the items in a column are black. And you could ensure that you only find those columns after a column that had some white in it

Comment: You want what are called the "connected components" of the image. You can achieve this with a single function call in scikit-image and also in opencv. Additionally, if you want one additional pixel around each component, simply *dilate* the image first (this means to expand all the white regions).

Answer (score 1):

Do you want only the image or the digit itself (as an integer)?

If you want to separate the white digits, I suggest you to look at OpenCV and its  [Canny Edge Detector](https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/da/d22/tutorial_py_canny.html)

It can detect the edges of your digits, as a list of pixels

Answer (score 0):

This will do it:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

image = cv2.imread('image.png')


def consecutive(data):
    return np.split(data, np.where(np.diff(data) != 1)[0]+1)


spl = list(map(lambda x: x[-1], 
    consecutive(np.unique(np.argwhere(image.sum(axis=0) < 30)[:, 0]))))

splits = np.split(image, spl, axis=1)
```

Example:

[image]